# Laravel 8: Unable to locate a class or view for component [dashboardHeader]

Tags: laravel

Everything was fine in my localhost. But after putting in online server I am facing many errors. I got this error and there is not case sensitivity issue in name.

Here is my class name in `app->http->view/component`

```
class dashboardHeader extends Component
```

And here is my calling tag of component in view file.

```
<x-dashboardHeader />
```

I also tried this way

```
<x-dashboardHeader> </x-dashboardHeader>
```

But still it is not working!

Comment: You've asked the same question with the "User" class problem and got the answer already. Please go through https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/ and read it. Classes should be named strictly following these guidelines (and Laravel respects and follows them). So your class should be named **DashboardHeader** and the tag to display would be **<x-dashboard-header>**.

Comment: @Thepeanut Okay, strangly it is worked! But please tell me why it worked with your given tag `<x-dashboard-header />`. I mean.... If I have created component with `artisan` command with this name `dashboardheader`, then why it didn't pick my chosen name? Why laravel made modifications and added hifun (`-`) symbol in between? Where I can see the correct name of calling tag since it is not taking my chosen name for calling component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will put this as an answer since it's too big for the comment.

When you put **x-dashboardHeader** tag in your template - Laravel is actually trying to load your **DashboardHeader** class (notice the uppercase D) from the **View\Components** namespace (read it as **LARAVEL_ROOT\App\View\Components\DashboardHeader.php**).
It does it using the autoloader which is generated by the composer.

While developing using Windows/MacOS - case sensitivity for the file name isn't a problem, since in those systems you can't have two files with the same name (independent of the name casing). So if you have a file named "myCoolFile" - you can access it using "mycoolfile", "MyCoolFile", etc....

But this isn't the case for unix systems. In those systems file names are case-sensitive. You can have 3 files named "myCoolFile", "mycoolFile", "MyCoolFile" and this won't be a problem. You can test it yourself using:

```
touch myCoolFile
touch MyCoolFile
touch mycoolfile
ls -l
```

So going back to Laravel trying to load your **LARAVEL_ROOT\App\View\Components\DashboardHeader.php** file, the file is named differently in your case **dashboardHeader.php**. And since **DashboardHeader.php** and **dashboardHeader.php** are different files in unix systems - you get the error.

I really hope that I could describe the problem.

This is why I suggest that you might want to read the [PHP-PSR](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/) docs (which, again, Laravel follows) where it says that classes MUST be named using **StudlyCaps**. So no "dashboardHeader", no "dashboard_Header" and stuff like that, only "DashboardHeader", "MyCoolClass" and so on.